# Simple Item Counting VBA Function

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose we have an 'account number' header under which a number of account numbers are listed with 2-3 blank spaces between them.

For each instance of this header I would like to be able to count the number of non-blank cells below, and end the count when the number of blank cells in a row is greater than or equal to 4.  Each count could appear in a row of Column A in an existing sheet or a new sheet.

I have asked a similar question to this and believe the way I have stated it here simplifies the process a bit.  The only catch is that there is other text in the column and so in order to count an instance "Account Number" one will need to first find that instance, iterating for all instances.

Would anyone happen to have a good idea of how to do this using Excel VBA?  Thanks!  A block of the spreadsheet would look like below:

```
Other Text 
Other Text
Other Text

Account Number

12345



23456


34567



45678


Other Text
Other Text

Account Number
```

On another sheet the output would effectively just be a column of numbers such as:

```
4 'as in the example above
6
5
14
4
15
```

Comment: A great place to start would be with a `For...Next` loop through column 1 (A). Here's an MSDN link that covers `For...Next` loops: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx. Inside that loop, you'll want to check to see if a cell is blank by using some permutation of `.Cells(y, x).Value <> ""`. Try experimenting with those two building blocks then posting your results: from there the VBA wizards on S.O. will help you if you get stuck :)

Comment: @Dan Thanks, I'll play around with that so that at the very least I can make use of it in the future.

Comment: Great -- looking forward to your code. It might also be helpful if you added a section to your post with what your ideal output would look like too

Comment: @Dan I'm trying to find a way to use .Find.  Would it make sense to set up a For loop that goes through the entries in the ctrl+F 'Find All' box.  Something of the effect of For Index = 1 To xlLastEntry.  Have you dealt with anything like that before or was the loop you had in mind avoiding .Find?

Comment: That is one possibility. If I were writing a script for this (and I'll try to whip one up today), I would use an `If` statement to increment a counter variable like so: `If AccountNumberSheet.Cells(y, x).Value = "" Then Counter = Counter + 1`. The `Else` of that statement might say something like `OutputSheet.Cells(w, v) = Counter` before initializing `Counter` to zero

Comment: @Dan I realize now that my example was a poor one!  A key issue that I failed to make explicit is that there are other values in the column other than the account number.  As such, the only way to know where to start would be to find a cell containing "account number".

Comment: I think the code below will do the trick

Comment: Did the script work, or are there more corner cases to worry about here?

Comment: @Dan Sorry, I only just got back to the data today.  The code is excellent, especially because it's very easy to read and see what's going on.  The only modification I am looking for is one to address the fact that Account Numbers can be alphanumeric (though they are not always).  I am thinking that a rule that the value have length greater than 6 might do the trick since the only other solution I can think of involves cataloguing each of the non-numeric "starting codes" that can precede a given account number.

Comment: Cool -- if you can get a list of all the account numbers, you could adjust the design to check against a `Collection` object containing the list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y8b3b3(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Dan Thanks!  I'll take a look through that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if this works... my criteria for an account number are commented in, but here they are again: (1) account number is numeric and (2) is 5-digits (i.e. > 9999)

```
Option Explicit
Sub CaptureAccountNumbers()

'criteria for an account number:
'1. is numeric
'2. is 5-digits (i.e. > 9999)

Dim DataSheet As Worksheet, OutSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, TargetCol As Long, StartRow As Long, _
    Index As Long, CountOfAccountNumbers As Long, _
    ResultCounter As Long

'set variables for easy reference
Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set OutSheet = Worksheets.Add
'delete any previously-existing "Results" worksheets
If DoesSheetExist("Results", ThisWorkbook) Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
OutSheet.Name = "Results"
TargetCol = 1 'i.e. column A
CountOfAccountNumbers = 0
StartRow = 0
ResultCounter = 1
LastRow = FindLastRowInCol(DataSheet, TargetCol)

'find the first occurence of "Account Number"
For Index = 1 To LastRow
    If DataSheet.Cells(Index, TargetCol) = "Account Number" Then
        StartRow = Index
        Exit For
    End If
Next Index

'loop through column A identifying account numbers
For Index = StartRow + 1 To LastRow
    If DataSheet.Cells(Index, TargetCol) = "Account Number" Then
        OutSheet.Cells(ResultCounter, TargetCol) = CountOfAccountNumbers
        CountOfAccountNumbers = 0
        ResultCounter = ResultCounter + 1
    Else
        If IsNumeric(DataSheet.Cells(Index, TargetCol)) And DataSheet.Cells(Index, TargetCol) > 9999 Then
            CountOfAccountNumbers = CountOfAccountNumbers + 1
        End If
    End If
Next Index

'write out the last account numbers if there are any
If CountOfAccountNumbers > 0 Then
    OutSheet.Cells(ResultCounter, TargetCol) = CountOfAccountNumbers
End If

End Sub

Public Function FindLastRowInCol(flricSheet As Worksheet, flricColumn As Long) As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    If flricColumn <> 0 Then
        With flricSheet
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, flricColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        End With
    Else
        LastRow = 1
    End If
    FindLastRowInCol = LastRow
End Function

Public Function DoesSheetExist(dseWorksheetName As String, dseWorkbook As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim obj As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    'if there is an error, sheet doesn't exist
    Set obj = dseWorkbook.Worksheets(dseWorksheetName)
    If Err = 0 Then
        DoesSheetExist = True
    Else
        DoesSheetExist = False
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column the header appears on is B, you could begin with something like this

```
n = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count-1
```

Which will count all of the non-blank cells in the column that are constants (not a value derived from a formula) and subtracts 1 (for the header). You can then assign the value to Cell A1 with

```
Cells(1, 1).Value = n
```

If you could post a sample of the data as it would appear on the sheet for clarity it would help in the future.